# calling data from database from controller to view using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Controller:

```
public function index() {
    $data = DB::table('tusers','tbills','tpackages')
    ->join('tbills', 'tusers.user_id', '=', 'tbills.user_id')
    ->join('tpackages', 'tbills.package_id', '=', 'tpackages.package_id')
    ->select('tusers.user_id','tusers.company_name','tusers.first_name', 'tbills.account_no', 'tpackages.package_name','tbills.start_date','tbills.end_date','tbills.bill_status')
    ->get();

    return View::make('account')->with('data',$data);
}
```

`

view:

```
@forelse($data as $value)
    <td>{{ $value->user_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->company_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->account_no }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->package_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->start_date }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->end_date }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->bill_status }}
```

I want to call $data from packagecontroller to account.blade but there is an error

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "tusers" does not exist
LINE 1: ... "tbills"."end_date", "tbills"."bill_status" from "tusers" i...
^ (SQL: select "tusers"."user_id", "tusers"."company_name", "tusers"."first_name", "tbills"."account_no", "tpackages"."package_name", "tbills"."start_date", "tbills"."end_date", "tbills"."bill_status" from "tusers" inner join "tbills" on "tusers"."user_id" = "tbills"."user_id" inner join "tpackages" on "tbills"."package_id" = "tpackages"."package_id")
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your table `tusers` is not defined. Did you try to write `users` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the other 2 table names from `table()`. Something like this.

```
public function index() {
    $data = DB::table('users','bills','packages')
    ->join('bills', 'users.id', '=', 'bills.user_id')
    ->join('packages', 'bills.package_id', '=', 'packages.id')
    ->select('users.id','users.company_name','users.first_name', 'bills.account_no', 'packages.package_name', 'bills.start_date', 'bills.end_date', 'bills.bill_status')
    ->get();

    return view('account', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

Mind column naming please. I may have changed some names, so you have to make sure you have the correct names.

In your view do

```
@foreach( $data as $value )
    <td>{{ $value->company_name }}</td>
    ...
@endforeach
```

It seems you are skipping some steps. Learn properly through this free video series how to work with Laravel: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017